# Make a css object mobile friendly

Tags: html, css

I have made a css script for a rectangular box with dashed border. Here is the css:

```
.stitched {
   padding: 20px;
   margin: 10px;
   background: #ff0030;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   border: 2px dashed #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ff0030, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
   text-shadow: -1px -1px #aa3030;
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="stitched">

  content....................................................

</div>
```

but in mobile version the content overlaps each other because the height of the box remains same and width reduces to fit mobile screen.
Any Help? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `@media`?

Comment: Does this work [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kstvm07y/2/)

Comment: just use `word-break: break-word;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some dummy text to test the code.

I understand that your content was overflowing earlier, to solve this I added

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

to ensure that content doesn't cross the borders.

```css
.stitched {
   padding: 20px;
   word-wrap:break-word;
   margin: 10px;
   background: #ff0030;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   border: 2px dashed #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ff0030, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
   text-shadow: -1px -1px #aa3030;
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="stitched">

  content
  <br>
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam 

</div>
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kstvm07y/2/)

**Alternatively, as the @Sam Teng Wong suggested, you can also use media queries like this.** Feel free to change anything as per your requirements.

```
@media(max-width:500px){
  .stitched {
   padding: 10px;
   word-wrap:break-word;
   margin: 5px;
   background: #ff0030;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 1em;
   border: 1px dashed #fff;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ff0030, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
   text-shadow: -1px -1px #aa3030;
   font-weight: normal;
}
}
```

Here is a [DEMO for the code with Media Queries](https://jsfiddle.net/h0h373yn/)

Comment: Alternative worked great! Exactly what i wanted :D thanks alot!